# How to edit SSMS Script Table As templates?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, templates, ssms

In the context menu of a table in SQL Server Management Studio there are several items under the common item `Script Table as`:

```
SELECT to
INSERT to
UPDATE to
DELETE to
..
```

and the same for all objects, e.g. stored procedures, functions, etc.

How can I edit the templates used by that menus?

Comment: @Mitch: Please post as an answer to be accepted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot edit the templates used by SQL Server Management Studio (which would be a nice feature).

You can create your own (parameterised templates) in `C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Shell\Templates\Sql`  (for SQL Server 2008)

Answer (score 1):

What do you want to do with this?

Have you seen the [SSMS tools pack](http://www.ssmstoolspack.com/Features) which adds some right click options?

Comment: I want to "normalize" them relatively to my style and remove elements being unnecessary for me and other junk